# FQDN with route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I guess I am bit confused about how Route53 handles FQDN.
Let's say I have a host named `abc`
My domain is `example.com`
I have an A record in route53 to route `https://abc.example.com` to my EC2 IP, assuming I have configured SSL correctly.
How can I make `https://abc` route to the same FQDN `https://abc.example.com` using route53?
We have that working in our Datacenter so I would assume it would be possible to implement in AWS?

Comment: To help get you on track to understanding this issue, let's start with which OS you are using in the data center. Is it primarily Linux or primarily Windows?

Comment: OS is data center is Linux

Comment: So, in `/etc/resolv.conf` your data center servers have an entry like `search example.com` (your domain)?

Comment: yes it does it's like so: `search <some root hosted zone> example.com misc`. It also has a reference to the `nameserver [IP]`. Do you think the name server is handling this?